# asterisk: double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c, asterisk

I'm going to splice a long string using ast_malloc and ast_realloc functions.When I load this module it will occur segment fault.What's the problem? much thanks!
Asterisk's output like this:

```
*** glibc detected *** asterisk: double free or corruption (fasttop):     0x00007fd56c000b20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33b9675f3e]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33b9678dd0]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33b967bd60]
/lib64/libc.so.6(realloc+0x158)[0x33b967c058]
/usr/lib64/asterisk/modules/app_test2.so(func+0x25)[0x7fd5330d19c5]
/usr/lib64/asterisk/modules/app_test2.so(+0xa92)[0x7fd5330d1a92]
asterisk[0x5175d5]
asterisk(ast_load_resource+0x34)[0x51a924]
asterisk[0x4c0f80]
asterisk(ast_cli_command_full+0x162)[0x4c3ad2]
asterisk(ast_cli_command_multiple_full+0x7c)[0x4c3cfc]
asterisk[0x450b9a]
asterisk[0x5c41cb]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x33b9a07aa1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x33b96e8aad]
```

And the codes shown below:

```
#include "asterisk.h"
#include "asterisk/module.h"
#include "asterisk/strings.h"
#include "asterisk/json.h"
#include "asterisk/res_odbc.h"

ASTERISK_FILE_VERSION(__FILE__, "$Revision$")

#define AST_MODULE "app_test"

void func(char* test, const char* src)
{
    char* new_test = (char*)ast_realloc(test, strlen(test) + 32);

    if ( NULL == new_test ){
        ast_log(LOG_ERROR, "realloc error\n");
        return;
    }

    test = new_test;
    strcat(test, src);
}

static int load_module(void)
{

    int i;
    char* test;
    char* src = "MingYuan";
    test = (char*)ast_malloc(16);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        func(test, src);
    }

    ast_log(LOG_DEBUG, "\n++++\n%s\n*******\n", test);
    ast_free(test);

    return AST_MODULE_LOAD_SUCCESS;
}

static int unload_module(void)
{

    return 0;
}

AST_MODULE_INFO(
    ASTERISK_GPL_KEY, AST_MODFLAG_LOAD_ORDER, "APP_TEST",
    .load = load_module,
    .unload = unload_module
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen(test)` within `func` is meaningless as you haven't copied a string into `test`; this is likely to cause erratic behaviour. My suggestion is, after `test = (char*)ast_malloc(16);` you probably want something like `strcpy(test, "");` or `test[0] = '\0';`...

As a result of pass-by-value semantics in C, these changes won't be visible to `func`'s caller:

```
test = new_test;
strcat(test, src);
```

The caller will have an old, invalidated pointer value somewhere in a pointer variable, which is sure to cause more erratic behaviour when used again later...

My suggestion is that you develop functions so that the *caller allocates memory*; this won't just fix your problem, but it'll allow you to be much more flexible with *how* your memory is allocated, much more often.

Comment: Note: It might work some number of times, if the reallocation doesn't require the memory block to be relocated. As soon as relocation is necessary though, everything breaks when you try to use the caller's now defunct pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It helps me a lot.I will take you suggestion.Thank you!